# How do I remove this eventListener in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove this eventListener in JS?

My try - not working

```
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
        if( e.clientY < 0 ) {
            $('.intent-exit-popup').show("slow");
        };

        document.removeEventListener("click", function(){
        $(".close-popup").click(function() {
            $('.intent-exit-popup').hide("slow");
        })
        }, true);

}, true);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: This is code for those terrible pop ups that appear all over the internet when you move off a page.. Really sucky UI design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by this way:

```
var mouseLeaveFired = false;
if (!mouseLeaveFired) {
    console.log('mouseLeave')
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
        mouseLeaveFired = true;
        e.target.removeEventListener('mouseleave', false)
    });
}
```

Comment: I dont know what am I doing wrong, but it doesnt seem to work your solution

Comment: In your code after removing the listener you are created a new listener here:  document.addEventListener("mouseleave") so you should check if it created at ones it should not creat a new listener.